# how to use multiple permission middleware in single method of resource controller in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Entrust Laravel 5 package. how to use index function in both the middleware in  _construct function in controller below:-

Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'v1', 'middleware'=> 'auth:api'], function(){

Route::resource('jobInstructionForm', 'API\V1\JobInstruction\JobInstructionController')->except('create');

});

controller

 public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('permission:manage.jobInstructions')->except('edit');
        $this->middleware('permission:approve.jobInstructionForm')->only('edit');
    }
```